# Sorting or Arranging an Array with a standard array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to sort a dyanamic javascript array which is being fetched everytime from Database. The condition is i want to sort it according to the values stored in a particular order in a standard pre-defined array.

Lets say my Dyanamic array is like :

```
var dbArray = ['Apple','Banana','Mango','Apple','Mango','Mango','Apple'];
```

and suppose the standard array against which i have to sort the above array is like

```
var stdArray = ['Mango','Apple','Banana','Grapes'];
```

So after sorting dbArray, my resultant array should look like :

```
var resultArray = ['Mango','Mango','Mango','Apple','Apple','Apple','Banana'];
```

As it is sorted keeping stdArray as the sorting criteria, which can be in any order regardless of alphabetical or any other standard sorting orders which are available, pure custom sorting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution is pretty slow, but should work

```
dbArray.sort(function(a,b) { 
    return stdArray.indexOf(a) - stdArray.indexOf(b);
});
```

If you're concerned about performance, you could use a map to track the index of each item to avoid scanning the array for each comparison.

```
var indexMap ={};
stdArray.forEach(function(str) {
    indexMap[str]=stdArray.indexOf(str);
});

dbArray.sort(function(a,b) { 
    return indexMap[a] - indexMap[b];
});
```

Comment: @Davidbarker Not anymore.

Comment: Nice, I like the second example!

Comment: @JuanMendes : Yeah that's nice, solved the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a typical sort and base the comparison off the index of `a` compared with the index of `b` in your reference array.

```
dbArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return stdArray.indexOf(a) - stdArray.indexOf(b);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dbArray = ['Apple','Banana','Mango','Apple','Mango','Mango','Apple'];
var stdArray = ['Mango', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Grapes'];
var sortArray = [];
stdArray.forEach(function (a) {
    while (dbArray.indexOf(a) !== -1) {
        sortArray.push(dbArray.splice(dbArray.indexOf(a), 1));
    }
});
sortArray.push(dbArray);
console.log(sortArray); // Mango,Mango,Mango,Apple,Apple,Apple,Banana,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dbArray = ['Apple','Banana','Mango','Apple','Mango','Mango','Apple'];

var stdArray = ['Mango','Apple','Banana','Grapes'];

var resultArray = new Array();
```

.

```
var i,l, k=0,isort=0;

for(i=0; i<stdArray.length; i++)
{  
  k = dbArray.filter(function(x){return x==stdArray[i]}).length;
  for(l=0; l<k; l++)
 {
    resultArray[isort + l] = stdArray[i];    
 }

 isort += k;

}
```

//CHECK:

```
var resultString = "";
 for(i=0; i<resultArray.length; i++)
 {
 resultString += resultArray[i];
 resultString += " ";  

 }

 alert(resultString);
```